# Increase scrollbar width (Ubuntu Studio 14.10)

Tags: settings, ubuntu-studio, overlay-scrollbars

How can I change the width of the scrollbars? (.. .. .. in menus, in settings, in firefox)

- I want to help my mother (72) using a computer too, but her eyes and orientation is less than mine, so it will help a lot if the indicators on the scrollbars are more visible (wider and perhaps more contrast), as touch and vision work together, wider is priority!
- I do know how to use a computer, even with different operating systems, but requirement is above my experience and I am looking for a more easy and less elaborate solution.

Thanks everybody for help !!!

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread: http://lists.kde.org/?l=kde&m=117313789128261 it is a Style-thing under "Application Appearance" in 'System Settings'. Here you can configure the 'Widget style' by using the button after the name of the 'Widget style'. Then you can change the width under the 'Scrollbars'-tab (with the standard Oxygen 'Widget style').